# Bootstrap Sidebar Min-Height Same As Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a content and sidebar layout in bootstrap and am having issues making the sidebar being the same height as the parent .row (its height is the same as the content's height). Is it possible to stretch the height of the sidebar to the height of the parent without using JS/JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the easiest way to do this is if your sidebar is positioned absolute and you set it's height to 100%, of course the wrapper should be positioned relative.

Comment: There is no other better way? It gets the job done but it seems a bit haxxy.

Comment: I found this, but I's a little bit more to write http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks